# How to send SSE on every DB change

Tags: jakarta-ee, server-sent-events

I have controller:

```
     @GET
       @Path("/info")
        @Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
        public EventOutput findInfoFromDb() {
             new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
      final OutboundEvent.Builder eventBuilder = new OutboundEvent.Builder();
 Optional objectDTO = finder.findObject();
        eventBuilder.name("object");
        eventBuilder.mediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
        eventBuilder.data(ObjectDTO.class, objectDTO);
OutboundEvent event = eventBuilder.build(); 
eventOutput.write(event);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }                }).start();
            return eventOutput;
        }
```

The problem I am facing is that every time I change sth in DB - I get several responses. How can I compare these objects I am getting from DB in aim to show only the changed one, without refreshing the page?

Comment: From what I See you should receive the 1st event and that stops. shouldn't you expose the eventOutput to trigger on each database modification instead of using a thread?

Comment: Could You provide me of an example of what You have in mind?